# Removing fragments from my ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding my `Fragments` in my main `Activity`. Can I remove or replace my `Fragment`s on `Fragment` changes?

```
 MyFragment mList = new MyFrament();   
 getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()        
.remove(mList)
.commit();
```

In which lifecycle method of the `Fragment` class should I call the `remove()` or `replace()` method. I am just confused whether I should call them in `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, or `onActivityCreate()`.

Comment: It's not clear if you want the `Fragment` to remove itself

Comment: @gipi: nope... when i am inside a fragment, there is a right and left menu fragment which needs to be changed/removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I know you better with calling the `remove()` and `replace()` methods from the parent `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` class in this case, and not from with in the `Fragment`.

And there is no need to instantiate a new instance of a fragment:

```
MyFragment mList = new MyFrament();
```

if you want just to remove it using the `SupportFragmentManager`.

**UPDATE:**

As for your second question, if you're currently removing a `Fragment` from your container (any `Layout` you are putting your fragments to, R.id.containerForFragments in next case ) then you have already instantiated an instance of this `Fragment` and added it using the:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()        
.add(R.id.containerForFragments, mList, tag)
.commit();
```

command. As you can see, you can specify a tag to your fragment that you can use later to get this `Fragment` instance back from the `FragmentManager` using the:

```
fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

command.

So to remove a `Fragment` for example do this:

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();
```

Comment: How would i get the reference mList

Comment: you could use the findFragmentById() method

Comment: @gipi: can u show me an example of findFragmentById(), coz if my fragments are all getting added/replaced in a single framelayout... how can i determine..

Comment: Should each fragment have a seperate framelayout and id.

Comment: its up to you and the way you want to arrange your fragments on screen.

Comment: lets take, i am adding three fragments to a same framelayout dynamically, at this context how would i determine which one to remove. this is how my class looks... https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/LeftAndRightActivity.java

Comment: you specify a unique tag to each one of them, and remove the one that you want.

Comment: one last question, lets take i have a tag = "Home" for a fragment, could you show me the exact code on how i would check for this home tag and do some operation... thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: here I find a fragment by tag and remove it: fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();

you can assign a tag at .replace() operation as well.

Comment: can't i not do a check operation with the tag like if(tag === home) // do something